# Find $ \frac{1}{2^2 –1} + \frac{1}{4^2 –1} + \frac{1}{6^2 –1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{20^2 –1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the following sum

> $$
> \frac{1}{2^2 –1} + \frac{1}{4^2 –1} + \frac{1}{6^2 –1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{20^2 –1}
> $$

I am not able to find any short trick for it.
Is there any short trick or do we have to simplify and add it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Use $$\frac2{n^2-1}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1}.$$

Comment: Don't forget to accept a correct answer if one has been posted.

Answer (score 8):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac12\left(1-\frac{1}{21}\right)=\frac{10}{21}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma to find the sum of $n$ terms of a series each term of which
is composed of the reciprocal of the product of $r$ factors in arithmetical progression,
the first factors of the several terms being in
the same arithmetical progression:**

Write down the $nth$ term,
strike off a factor from the beginning,
divide by the number of factors so diminished and by the common difference,
change the sign and add a constant.

In our case, the general term is $T_n$=$$\frac 1 {(2n)^2-1}$$

Which is simply, $$\frac 1 {(2n-1)(2n+1)}$$

Applying the lemma, we get:

$$S_n=C-(\frac 1 2)(\frac 1 {2n+1})$$

$$S_n=C-\frac 1 {4n+2}$$
Where $C$ is a constant quantity.

Putting $n=1$ in general term, we get:

$$S_1=\frac 1 3=C- \frac 1 {4+2}$$

That gives $$C=\frac 1 2$$

Thus, $$S_n=\frac 1 2-\frac 1 {4n+2}$$

Putting $n=10$ gives:

$$S_{10}=\frac 1 2-\frac 1 {40+2}$$
$$S_{10}=\frac 1 2-\frac 1 {42}$$
$$Or, S_{10}=\frac {20} {42}=\frac {10} {21}$$
 Which is the desired answer.

The method is a bit, long... But it is great for the so-called "bashing" through such problems. If you wish to see a proof, I refer you to Hall and Knight's Higher Algebra.

(P.S. I did this long answer with this specific method just so I could get a hang of the typing system in StackExchange. So, please forgive me even if the method seems useless... I'm new here...)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the telescoping sum decomposition, there is an easy pattern

$$\frac13$$

$$\frac13+\frac1{15}=\frac25$$

$$\frac13+\frac1{15}+\frac1{35}=\frac37$$

$$\frac13+\frac1{15}+\frac1{35}+\frac1{63}=\frac49$$

$$\cdots$$

Comment: To use this rigorously in an open-ended answer (as opposed to just multiple choice), one needs to prove the pattern by induction.